# Most memory efficient way of concatenating content from different pickle files

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pickle

I am getting a memory error when reading multiple pickle files and concatenating them:

```
train_data = numpy.concatenate([read_p(fn) for fn in train_data_filenames], axis=0)
```

where `train_data_filenames` is just a list of the filenames as strings.

my aux function `read_p(fn)` goes as follows:

```
def read_p(filename):
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        return pickle.load(f)
```

Is there a way of executing the concatenating more efficiently?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the memory efficiency of `concatenate`.   If you have 1000 files, each with an array of 500 elements, the `train_data` will have to have 1000*500 elements.  There's no way around that.

Comment: Please always use the generic [python] tag for all python related questions

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for that, but it looks that I read everything in the memory as a list first, then I concatenate the lists, so for that operation, I would need around double the memory space of the files (one time for the list and one time for the np object generated by np.concatenate) is that the case, or is the object transformed "in-place"? And if it's not transformed from list to np array "in-place", is there a way to either avoid the creation of the list or to force the "in-place" casting?